# Response.IsClientConnected always true with IE9

Tags: asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-9

I have a long running web page that I need to kill if the user navigates away (it loads the page in an iframe) but Response.IsClientConnected always returns true even if the user navigates to a different page.

Fiddler reports that the connection still happens.

Any ideas on how I can determine if the user leaves the page?

Cheers!

Comment: You can probably use onbeforeunload to determine when you have to send an ajax message to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VS development web server or IIS? HttpResponse.IsClientConnected worked correctly when code ran under IIS, but not under Cassini (dev. web server).

By the way, Fiddler itself can be the reason of a lasting connection. I noticed that if Fiddler's working, connection is active longer. In some test scenarios I've implemented in my projects a web application (code depended on IsClientConnected) worked fine without Fiddler running, but turning Fiddler on brought bugs immediately.